# Trying to parse the time

Tags: java, string, type-conversion

I have String

```
   String aa="01:30";
   String hh=aa.substring(0,2);
   String mm=aa.substring(3,5);
```

I am trying to parse the seperated values by using

```
int hh=Integer.parseInt(hhs);
int mm=Integer.parseInt(mms);
```

The out put is 1 and 30 How can I solve to get output as it is like 01 & 30?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your string variable names are missing the s that you refer to in your parse int

Comment: What are hhs and mms? They aren't defined anywhere. Integers cannot have a leading zero and your substring isn't pulling the right data for 30 if you are getting just the 3. You only need the "1" to know it is 1 O'clock if you want to display it back to the user just do it as a string concatenated with a leading "0" EDIT: as the @giacomoni said it returns 1 and 30....

Comment: I tried your code, and the output is 1 and 30, not 1 and 3

Comment: Hey, did you solve this? can you accept an answer or add the right answer to close this question and get it off the unanswered list, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An integer can't store leading zeroes. If you are getting 3 for mm though it indicates you have another problem, as that should resolve to 30

Comment: Any integer literal that starts with a 0 followed by other digits is octal, and this will further confuse things if the OP tries to force it to have the leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Saying you want an integer value *and* you want a leading zero is contradictory. Numeric data types have just the number value; only a String representation of that number has a leading zero.

So you need to decide… Do you want:

- An integer (example: 1)
- A String (example: 01)
- A time (example: 01:30)

Generally if working with date-time values, you should treat them as such. Rather than use the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date/Calendar classes, use either the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library or the new java.time.* classes in Java 8.

Example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

```java
String input = "01:30";
LocalTime localTime = new LocalTime( input );
int hourOfDay = localTime.getHourOfDay();
int minuteOfHour = localTime.getMinuteOfHour();
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "localTime: " + localTime );
System.out.println( "hourOfDay: " + hourOfDay );
System.out.println( "minuteOfHour: " + minuteOfHour );
```

When run…

```
localTime: 01:30:00.000
hourOfDay: 1
minuteOfHour: 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always do formatting

like this

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("00");
System.out.println("HH "+df.format(hh));
```

That will give 01 as the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
String aa="01:30";

String hhs=aa.substring(0,2);
String mms=aa.substring(3,5);

int hh=Integer.parseInt(hhs);
int mm=Integer.parseInt(mms);

String hh_formatted = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%02d", hh);
String mm_formatted = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH,"%02d", mm);
```

Using above only you can get your desired output in string format.

Comment: Do you think you can do it in Java :)? Check above comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/21456496/3248256

Answer (score 0):

Time specific things should be done with Date()..

```
        SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    SimpleDateFormat outHourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH");
    SimpleDateFormat outMinFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm");

    String outHour = null;
    String outMinute = null;
    Date input;

    try {
        input = inFormat.parse("03:30");
        outHour = outHourFormat.format(input);
        outMinute = outMinFormat.format(input);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // now you got two Strings: outHour & outMinute in correct form.
```

Comment: by the way .. int with leading 0 is not possible